# Find references of code that updates objects of a specific class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, resharper

Is there a way to find references of code that updates objects of a class in VS 2015 with Resharper?

Example: let's say I have the following code:

```
public class A {
        public int Prop1 {get; set;}
        public void Update()
        {
            Prop1 = 100
        }
        public String ToString() 
        {
          return Prop1.ToString();
        }
}

some code:

A a = new A();
a.Prop1 = 100; // write access

a.Update(); // write access

Console.Writeln(a); // read-only access
```

I want a way of finding only those statements that modify the objects of a class A. In the code above that would be the lines where I have the comment `// write access`. Resharper can find all the usages of a class but there is too much noise from read-only usages such as linq queries, and I wanted to see only the updates. Reporting the constructor call is fine. Reporting only the statements that set the properties of the objects of class A would be fine as well. The classes that I want to find the updates for are EF entities and they have only a few methods or none.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReSharper solution: you can find all usages of the particular property and then there are two separate buttons in results window to show read or write usages separately.

[image: See picture]

Comment: Thank you! These buttons were in front of my my eyes and I missed them :-(

Comment: @costa - actually, another guy showed them to me just couple days before you asked this question - and it turned out that I missed them just the same :)

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a Resharper solution. More of a quick-and-dirty search. Assuming that the class is within your solution and there aren't way too many properties, change the properties to read-only. The compiler errors will show you anything that writes to the properties.

Comment: Thanks. Very good trick, though it would require some code changes - it's a small price to pay.